# C++ Model loading API?

Tags: c++, models, loading

I'm looking for **the most** capable C++ model loading API.

So far I've found tons of ply, obj, and other such file format loaders.  But the libraries I've found tend to load just **one** model type, and this requires you to learn quite a few api interfaces?

Is there One API To Load Them All, One API To Parse Them, One API To Bring Them All, And In the Vertex Buffer, Bind Them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) seems to be a good choice and I will be testing this with my next project. It supports a [huge](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_features_formats.html) array of formats including supporting bones and animations. Not just for model loading, but for changing from format to format, computing vertex and face normals, splitting meshes, and triangulating polygons. It is available under the BSD license.